Kubernetes Rest API failing with GOAWAY error
I have a strange error with accessing Kubernetes rest api. I am trying to do some operation with Kubernetes deployment which tested okay once and then not working.
I am able to do the operation with curl and once I was able to do with Java program as well. Now curl works however, Java program giving error
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                    .followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.ALWAYS)
                    .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
                    //.version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
                    .build();
            
            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .uri(URI.create("https://100.124.0.1:443/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/omnistore-services/deployments/test-deploy"))
                    //.version(Version.HTTP_1_1) 
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .header("Authorization","Bearer "+token)
                    .header("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate")
                    //.method("PATCH", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString("{\"name\": \"BMW X5 M Sport\"}"))
                    .method("GET", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody())
                    .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                    .build();
            
            HttpResponse<String> response = client
                    .send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

            System.out.println(response.statusCode());
            System.out.println(response.body());

Now, when testing with HTTP 2, it is giving java io exception GOAWAY error, which I tried a lot of options (apache http client as well). This error not going
While testing with HTTP1.1, it is failing with 401 authorisation error. Though I tested with curl http1.1 and it worked.
Not sure how to progress with this. Any help will be appreciated.

Any reason to not use the official client library?
